# What are the limits of docplex (the cplex version of python) in terms of the number of variables and constraints?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, cplex, docplex

I am solving an optimization problem in python using docplex(not docplex cloud API) with  only 2 constraints and 92 variables (dvar in OPL). But even though I get this error:

> docplex.mp.utils.DOcplexLimitsExceeded: **** Promotional version. Problem size limits exceeded, CPLEX code=1016

I would like to know if there is a student version for docplex, I was unable to find this information on the IBM website because as I understand there is a paid version for docplex cloud and not for docplex, and there is a student and paid version for IBM CPLEX ILOG Studio. What about docplex, is there any student version I can use?

Thank you in advance.

Regards.

**EDIT:** My problem got finally solved using Mr. @AlexFleischer answer(Thank you). Just a quick note for next students who want to use the IBM CPLEX ILOG Studio you will get this message:

> Error
>
> Your eligibility to order the following items is under review. You will be notified of your eligibility by email. Please retry your order at that time.
> IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio v12.8 - Student (CJ2IKML) - Download

It's actually not an "Error" as mentioned, it's a standard process where your institution is going to be checked by IBM to see if it's an eligible institution (it was an actual answer from an IBM employee).
This process took two days for me in order to be able to download the student version.
Also to install cplex and docplex don't use:

```
pip install cplex (or docplex)
```

instead use

```
python setup.py install
```

Regards

Comment: Why do you not try free solvers? Your problem is small, therefore you can solve it with them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually it's because my problem could scale to hundreds of variables plus my code is ready, and I did not want to code again from scratch. Regards.

Comment: Hey sel, my student licence of cplex_studio does only include folders that are called 'example'. There is no setup.py file in the cplex directory. Did you have the similar issue and how exactly did you install it then?

Comment: No sorry I did not have this problem, I had the setup.py. You can ask a new question on StackOverFlow or the IBM forum. The IBM folks answer usually quickly. Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datascience/blogs/xavier-nodet1/2020/07/09/cplex-free-for-students you'll get a free CPLEX for students. And inside you have all the APIs hence the docplex API.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is macOS Catalina 10.15.3 version with python 3.7 and IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio v12.9.

1. make sure you have installed the correct "IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio" version instead of "IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio **Community Edition**".
2. make sure you add CPLEX path to python path. That is to check the ".bash_profile" file should has: "export PYTHONPATH="/Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/cplex/python/3.7/x86-64_osx/:$PYTHONPATH"#"
3. open your Terminal, cd to your CPLEX python folder like this: %cd /Applications/CPLEX_Studio129/python/
4. type the command: %python setup.py install
5. type the command: %pip install cplex
6. type the command: %pip install docplex

Note that step 3,4,5 are executed in order.

Then, the DOcplexLimitsExceeded is solved in my laptop.
I hope this helps you!